# PHP Framework to support mssql_connect and stored procs

Tags: sql-server, zend-framework, codeigniter, php

I'm currently searching on the web to find a good PHP Framework for:

- **SQL Server 2000**
- can manage stored procedures calls that return more than 1 recordset at a time (for example **mssql_connect**)
- can use multiple database at the same time (**Ex:** Master and Client databases)

For now, I have a short list of candidates:

- CodeIgniter
- Kohana
- Zend Framework
- Fuel PHP
- CakePHP
- **Others ???**

Our goal is to be able to connect to a Master database for login purpose and then, connect to client database for specific data.

From what I can see, only CodeIgniter seems to be able to achieve those goals.

Comment: In case of Zend Framework you don't need to use supplied Zend_Db. You can replace it with any DB adapter you like. Maybe even the one from CodeIgniter ;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to go with Codeigniter.  There is an amazing community both in the irc chat channel, forums and it has the best documentation bar none.

You get your project done and when you have, then you look at any other alternatives to do anything you want done better.  As there are things the other frameworks can do better than Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Kohana is a great framework with active development.  I would recommend it, along with an ORM module called [Leap](https://github.com/spadefoot/kohana-orm-leap) that supports multiple different types of databases (including MSSQL).